# TexturePacker settings for phaser

Tags: javascript, json, settings, phaser-framework, texturepacker

Can anyone describe TexturePacker settings that work for phaser? I am using an atlas with the JSON hash format to place objects in my game... they are not even animated. But I am getting many "Cannot set frameName: someimage.gif" errors... what am i doing wrong? I actually did get it right once, with the free version of TexturePacker... then I bought it, tried to make some changes and cannot get it right again!

My TexturePacker settings:

### Data:

Data Format: json (hash)

### Texture

Texture format: PNG
Pixel format: RGBA8888

### Layout

Max size W/H: 4096
Size constraints: POT (Power of Two)
Force squared: on
Allow Rotation: off
Detect identical Sprites: on

### Sprites

Trim mode: Trim
Trim/Crop Threshold: 1
Pivot Point: Center
Extrude: 0
Border padding: 0
Shape padding: 0
Inner Padding: 0
Common divisor x: 1 y: 1

and nothing else turned on...

Answer (score 3):

We've added official support for Phaser with [TexturePacker 3.6.0](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker).

The JSON array and JSON data are now available from the framework selector.

We've also created a simple [tutorial](https://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2014/12/17/creating-spritesheets-for-phaser-with-texturepacker) showing you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I also use TexturePacker with Phaser. Work's great.

i use:

- JSON(Array)
- Max Size 2048
- constraint POT
- allow rotation: disable
- border padding:2
- shape padding: 2

Javascript:

```
// Load atlas
this.game.load.atlas('atlas-interface', 'assets/images/atlas_interface.png', 'assets/images/atlas_interface.json');

// Sprite creation
this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, "atlas-interface", "image1.png");
```